# How do I demand a 64-bit agent?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In the documentation for Azure Pipelines, it allows for `demands` to be provided which will force a task to select an agent with `capabilities` that meet the demands.

However, I can't find a definitive list of the capabilities provided by the Microsoft-hosted agents.

How can I specify a demand that will only allow for 64-bit agents?

Comment: What do you mean by "64 bit agents"? There's only one agent install, and whether it's 64 bit or 32 bit should not be relevant to your builds. Are you talking about 32 or 64 bit operating systems? Or some specific piece of software **installed** on the agent?

Comment: An agent running in a 64-bit environment.

Comment: It's a safe bet that every image used is 64 bit. Have you encountered any specific problems that would lead you to believe otherwise?

Comment: @Daniel-mann there is an x86 agent and a x64 agent and there are differences. The x86 agent, for example, can't execute legacy-powershell tasks.,

Comment: If you want to run tests on x64 and x86 to ensure platform compatibility for example, it's important to be able to specify each architecture for separate agents.

Comment: But you're right that at the moment all Hosted Pool agents run x64 and that adding a  demand isn't needed. Plus, Microsoft has cleared all capabilities from hosted and will always "just try" the build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For x64 you can add a demand for one of these:

```
Agent.OSArchitecture    X64
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE  AMD64
```

These will ensure you're running on an x86 or x64 bit operating system. Unfortunately, the agent's architecture isn't reflected in the capabilities.

Each machine in each pool runs the same CPU and OS architecture. For the standard hosted pools x64 is the default. If ARM based agents are added in the future, that may change.

Fortunately, you can add that capability yourself:
[image]

For your own agents you can check the **System capabilities** tab in the Agent Pool for available capabilities you can demand:

[image]